# How to run a newly created rqt plugin?

Tags: plugin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create an plugin for rqt. So far I have followed the tutorial "rqt/Tutorials/Create your new rqt plugin" on the ROS wiki exactly, but when I type "rosrun rqt_mypkg rqt_mypkg" I get the following message:

```
Couldn't find executable named rqt_mypkg below /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg
Found the following, but they're either not files, or not executables:
 /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg
 /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg/src/rqt_mypkg
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124706/how-to-run-a-newly-created-rqt-plugin?/) by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2014-01-30**:
I'm running groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 if that helps.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-30**:
Have you set your script as executable? Try chmod +x /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg/src/rqt_mypkg

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2014-01-31**:
I tried this, but I received the message "chmod could not access" ...."No such file or directory".
However, I did not notice this before, but if I run "rqt" the default rqt gui comes up. My plugin is listed under the Plugins tab. It throws a lot of errors when I click it though.

**Comment by [aland_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/11466/aland_t/) on 2014-01-31**:
Ok, I have the plugin working if I just run "rqt" and open it from the plugins menu. "rosrun rqt_mypkg rqt_mypkg" still does not work.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-02-02**:
@atland_t you can modify your post to paste the error you got.

**Comment by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) on 2014-09-12**:
Can you change the title of this question to "how to run a newly created rqt plugin". The Answer of "Wolf" is correct, so you can close this afterwards. I also updated the tutorial to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to put a phyton script like the following into your package `rqt_mypkg` and name it after the package `rqt_mypkg`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from rqt_gui.main import Main

main = Main()
sys.exit(main.main(sys.argv, standalone='rqt_mypkg'))
```

Now you can run you `rosrun rqt_mypkg rqt_mypkg` in oder for starting your plugin stand-alone, i. e. independent from rqt_gui; otherwise, you may want to load your plugin into rqt_gui....

Note, that the script file also needs to be executable; Maybe you need to run `chmod +x rqt_mypkg` in the folder where you have placed the rqt_mypkg script file. E. g. for an error msg like:

```
Couldn't find executable named rqt_mypkg below /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg
Found the following, but they're either not files, or not executables:
 /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg
 /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg/src/rqt_mypkg
```

go into the folder where the python script is placed in:

```
cd /home/alan/catkin_ws/src/rqt_mypkg/src/
```

and run there:

```
chmod +x rqt_mypkg
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-05**:
The `standalone` argument should contain the fully qualified name: like in https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/blob/5f0d4e6f9aa31f14e35754b056c35a3e673e065b/rqt_graph/scripts/rqt_graph#L8